# Increase Solr performance when querying a subset of documents

Tags: performance, caching, solr

**The Usecase**

I have an index of potentially millions of documents. I want to make around 20'0000 searches on a subset of these documents (around 25'000 documents). These 25'000 documents could take up around 100 MB stored in Solr (consisting of stored and indexes text fields).

**The Problem**

As the number of indexed documents increases, the performance of the queries decreases a lot. For example running 20'000 searches that hit 25'000 documents on 100'000 document index takes around 4 minutes. Running the same searches on 200'000 document index takes around 20 minutes.

So is there any way to cache these 25'000 documents in RAM before hitting them with searches?

**UPDATE**

**Some things that really helped:**

- **reducing returned row count** (In almost all cases I had to iterate through returned results and in almost all cases where were no more than 100 matching results, but I had set rows to a very large value. Reducing the row count improved the performance around 2x. This seemed counter intuitive. If there are only 79 matches and I set returned row count to 100 it performs better than in a case when where are 79 matches and I set the row count to 1000. In the first case Solr already returns found item count and does it fast. Why should there be a performance difference?)
- **reducing multithreading** (I had added multiple threads for querying because on the development box there were more resources available. On the resource constrained production box it was slowing things down. Using only one or two threads got me around 2x speed improvement.)

**Some things that did not really help:**

- **splitting up field queries** (I was already using field queries everywhere it was possible, but I was combining them in one fq for each query `fq=name:a AND type:b`. Splitting them up with `fq=name:a&fq=type:b` caches them separately (see [Apache Solr documentation](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#Caching_of_filters)) and could improve performance. But it did not make a huge difference in this case.
- **changing caching settings** in this case filterCache seemed to have the most potential. However, increasing it or changing its settings did not make a huge difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things that are recommended for performance:

- Have enough spare RAM on the box so index files can be in OS cache
- Try to play around with solr caching settings in SolrConfig
- Play around with autowarming after commits
- Try to develop your queries to limit the result set. Large result sets, specifically if using grouping and faceting will kill performance. Now 200,000 document index is really quite small, so you should not have any problems, but I thought I'd mention this for when you scale.

  - Try to use Filter query (FQ) whenever possible. They are much faster than doing field:val in q, plus they are cached.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Will try different caching options and leave a message here if there are any improvements. The thing is that RAM is pretty limited, so it would be good if I could somehow hint solr which documents should be cached.

Comment: sure, try to limit the query with FQ first, I have a feeling you will get the most bang for the buck there.

Comment: Sounds good, if you are using faceting in your queries, you can also play around with facet methods and facet threads.

Comment: Ended up moving Solr server to a faster box and got another 3-4x speed improvement.  The speed seems decent so I finally accept the suggestions in this answer.